# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myutils'"

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

How can it be that Visual Studio Code python debugger works ok while python interactive (aka jupyter notebook) gives "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_utils'" when I try to "import my_utils" this my module into my file?

The working directory is not the reason. 
Jupyter notebook is installed in Anaconda environment.

Comment: Maybe the Python path is different, or the Python installation environment is not the same

Comment: Can you show your project structure?

Comment: How can it be resolved? So the notebook could import my module in a file?

Comment: It is quite simple like Working directory--> working file, my_utils. Both files are in the same working directory